# Centering input field - issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I'd like to center an icon in the y-middle of an input field.

What I've tried was something like this:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 4%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcmsc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 2;
}

#input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #eae8ea;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eae8ea;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="input" />
  <div id="icon"></div>
</div>
```

For desktop safari (Mac OS) it is working quite fine but on mobile devices like on my iPhone the icon does not seems to be centered at all:

[image: img]

How to fix this error occurring on mobile devices? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is caused by default margin and padding for `input` element. Default values are used by browser and need to be overwritten to be nulled. `box-sizing: border-box;` ensures borders which you add to `#input` are collapsed to it's height and don't exceed it.

[Here you can read more about `border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

#### Default browser CSS (example)

[More about them](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

Here already partially overwritten.

[image]

#### Key part

```
#input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 4%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcmsc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 2;
}

#input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #eae8ea;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eae8ea;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="input" />
  <div id="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the `box-sizing` attribute will kill the specified height, etc.

Comment: It will not. Only make it collapse to defined dimension. If you don't want to user `box-sizing: border-box` you need to somehow move `#icon` by border's width. You can use margin, padding, `position: relative; top: Xpx` or so.

Comment: Huh? For me it does. Adding `"box-sizing: border-box;"` to the input will let it look different instantly. And I want the icon centered, what ever height the input element has.

Comment: Take a look at my snippet or please show JSFriddle showing your problem. As I mentioned above if you don't want to use this trick you need to move somehow `#icon` or center it diferently. For example using `display: flex; align-items: center` for container.

Comment: @jonas00 : could you please post an example of your problem? I'd like to help you, but without it it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I  see no reason that you can't just use a background image directly on the input? (I made some adjustments to the original example, but you get the idea)

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#input {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #eae8ea;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcmsc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="input" />
</div>
```